# String display only last object i add (C#)

Tags: c#, string

im trying to make quiz program but my string alfa save only last question (if question1 is answered wrong it saves that its wrong but if question2 is wrong it only saves that question 2 was wrong answered and overwrite that question1 was wrongly answered. I want to save all questions that had wrong answer not only last one, anyone know where I make mistake in my code ??

```
 public partial class Exam : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            ExamQuestionList questions;
            int questionNumber;
            string alfa;
            public int Score
            {
                get { return (int)ViewState["score"]; }
            }

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // initialise questionNumber and score
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    ViewState["questionNumber"] = 0;
                    ViewState["score"] = 0;

                }

                questions = (ExamQuestionList)Application["questions"];

                // update questionNumber
                questionNumber = (int)ViewState["questionNumber"] + 1;
                ViewState["questionNumber"] = questionNumber;

            }

            protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // display next question
                Question q = questions[questionNumber - 1];
                lblQuestion.Text = "Question " + questionNumber + ": " + q.QuestionText;
                rblOptions.DataSource = q.Options;
                rblOptions.DataBind();
                rblOptions.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

            protected void cmdNextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // update score based on the answer to the previous question
                int previousAnswer = rblOptions.SelectedIndex;
                Question previousQuestion = questions[questionNumber - 2];
                if (previousAnswer == previousQuestion.CorrectAnswer)
                    ViewState["score"] = (int)ViewState["score"] + 1;
                if (previousAnswer != previousQuestion.CorrectAnswer)
                    alfa =(questionNumber-1).ToString();
                if (alfa == null)
                Label1.Text ="";
                if (alfa != null)
                    Label1.Text = "you gave wrong answer to"+alfa;
                // redirect to Result.aspx, if this is the last question
                if (questionNumber == questions.Length) cmdNextQuestion.PostBackUrl = "~/Result.aspx";
            }

        }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any sort of loop or list in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are saving that information on variable "alfa". The problem is that alfa should be a List or have something to split the information.

With the code you have, you'll never get the result you are trying to get.

```
alfa =(questionNumber-1).ToString();
```

What you might try is to transform alfa in a List and change your code to something like (not tested)

```
string aux =(questionNumber-1).ToString();
alfa.Add(aux);
```

Edit: I just noticed you are working with ASP.NET and you need to keep information between requests. There are different options to do it, you can use cookies, session, control state, hidden fields, view state, query string and finally application state. Basically, you need to select one of them to save your current list and read it from it on the next request.

Comment: My questionNumber is int and it doesnt allow me to add it to list ;( (strange I think .ToString() should solve my problem)

Comment: I'm casting it to string as you might have the opportunity to see. Well, you may just have a list you ints. Please try harder, you will get the solution you are trying to achieve, but you cannot give up on the first problem.

Comment: Im still trying hard but my list got only one element, something is wrong any hint ?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't notice it was ASP.NET. Basically, you need to save that information between requests. You can do it using view state, session or hidden fields, cookies or control state.